# unable to validate user input in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate the user input in my the case the input is the color name entered by user, here is the code snippet

```
let valideColor = false;

do{

      const selected_color = $('#SelectedColorPicker').val();

        if (selected_color === '') {
            console.log('Not valid')
        }
        else {
            validColor = true;
        }

}while(!validColor)
```

the code above produces an infinite loop leading my browser to crash,
I would appreciate if anyone can tell me where the problem is .

Comment: You could use [`required` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required), or  an *event*, more like [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) to check that. And change `const` to `let` or `var`...

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: the goal is to display a modal box instead of console.log when the input is not valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got an infinite loop because you're running code continuously in a loop, not giving the user a chance to enter any input - when user input would be the only way to make `validColor` true and therefore break out of the loop.

A loop is totally the wrong approach here. You only need check at certain points, presumably when the user tries to submit whatever form this input is part of. So you should do something like this:

```
$("#idOfMyForm").submit(function(e) {
    const selected_color = $('#SelectedColorPicker').val();

    if (selected_color === '') {
        console.log('Not valid');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

to warn the user (although of course a mere `console.log` will not be noticeable to anyone who doesn't have the browser console open, so not the vast majority of users), and stop the form submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
let validColor = false
  $('#SelectedColorPicker').on("change",function(){
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        console.log('Not valid')
      }
      else {
        validColor = true;
      }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use input

```
$('#SelectedColorPicker').on("input", function() {
   var selected_color = this.value;
   console.log(selected_color);
});
```